# Justify that $ V(s)V'(s)=f(s,V(s))$ has locally exactly one solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Let $V:(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a solution of $ V(s)V'(s)=f(s,V(s))$ $(1)$

1.Justify that $(1)$ has locally exactly one solution with $V(s_{0})=V_{0}>0$.

2.If $(a,b)$ with $-\infty \leq a <s_{0} <b \leq \infty$ is the maximal existence interval, which possibilities exist for $V(s)$ if $s \downarrow$ and if $s \uparrow b$

I tried to integrate but i can´t solve the Integral $\int_{0}^{s}f(t,V(t))dt $.

Another idea was that we divide by $V(s)$ in a neightbourhood $U$of $s_{0}$ and conclude with $1/V(s)=F(s,V(s)) \in C^1(U)$ and use Picard-Lindelöf on $f*F \in C^1(u)$.

I´m not sure how to use this for task $2$ if it is right. Can someone give me some hints or something.

Comment: Your really wanted to write $V(s)V'(s)$ like in $\frac12\frac{d}{ds}(V(s)^2)$? Then set $y=V^2$ so that $y'=2f(t,\sqrt{y})$ and proceed from there.

Comment: What do u mean with procced from there? Integrating doesn't work.

Comment: You are not expected to solve this problem, you only need to apply the existence and uniqueness theorems. Locally you can approximate $f$ by a linear function because of its differentiability. The solution with this linear right side gives qualitative insight into the shape of solutions in this neighborhood. This might be helpful around $V=0$.

Comment: Remember that this is a dynamical system, its evolution can potentially lead to anywhere in the state space.

Comment: I don't get it, what you try to explain. Maybe my english is too bad by writing task 1. We have $(1)$ and $V(s_{0})=V_{0}>0$ so we shoud justify with that two things the locally exactly one solution. In my opinioln this follows direct from Picard-L.( existence and uniqueness) . So why is V=0 important? In an neighbourhood of $s_{0}$ is $V \neq 0$ then we get $V \in C^1$

Comment: I was mostly commenting on task 2), should have made clearer that your second idea on task 1) is correct. $V=0$ is interesting as one of the limit cases in 2). In the usual situation you would have divergence towards the boundaries of the domain, here infinity, as the only limit case for a finite boarder of the maximal existence interval.